Best Algorithm for arrange members of set with the least proximity between the members of different sets in Python
We have different sets. How to arrange different members next to each other in such a way that there is the least proximity between the members of the same set? And as much as possible none of the two members of the same set are next to each other?
For example
s1 = [m1, m1, m1, m1, m1, m1, m1, m1, m1, m1]
s2 = [m2, m2, m2, m2, m2]
s3 = [m3, m3, m3]

And the result must be something like this:
r1 = [m1,m2, m1,m2, m1, m2, m1,m2, m1,m2, m1,m3, m1,m3, m1,m3, m1, m1]

Notice: In this case, it is possible to split s1 into n sets to void this problem. And then arrange members. And n must be the minimum number.

"none of the two members of the same set are next to each other". Your example shows m1 can be next to each other?

In some cases, it happens. No problem with this situation. @OneCricketeer

If s1 has 2 more elements than s2, then you can't split the elements of s1 with only elements of s2 in such a way that no elements of s1 are adjacent.

It is possible to split s1 into two sets to void this problem.  @SimonGoater

I don't have an actual proof that this is optimal. I only suspect that it is. However I do know that it is simple, fast, and produces good results.
def distribute (count_by_kind):
    total_count = 0
    kinds = []
    current_weight = []
    for kind, count in count_by_kind.items():
        total_count += count
        kinds.append(kind)
        current_weight.append(0)

    max_i = -1
    max_weight = -1
    for _ in range(total_count):
        for i, kind in enumerate(kinds):
            current_weight[i] += count_by_kind[kind] / total_count
            if max_weight < current_weight[i]:
                max_weight = current_weight[i]
                max_i = i
        yield kinds[max_i]

        # Bookkeeping for the nexgt pass.
        current_weight[max_i] -= 1
        max_i = -1
        max_weight = -1

# An example of how to use it.
for x in distribute({"a": 5, "b":6, "c": 15}):
    print(x)

Incidentally this is cyclic. If you were to multiply all of the counts by n, you'll just get the same pattern repeated n times. If you wish to make the results unpredictable, you could initialize with a random number instead of 0. However then the most common element won't come first, which means that you might get an extra repeat.
